# AVD Manager don't start

Tags: android, sdk, android-virtual-device

(Solved see bellow)

My AVD Manager doesn't launch while SDK Manager works good... It worked once yesterday (so i could create one emulator) but now i can't access AVD Manager (no error, just don't launch).

When i Launch a program from Eclipse, my last emulator starts ok and all is good, but i can't manage it or create another one...

Any idea?

- Java is OK (JAVA_HOME...etc.)
- No space in SDK Path
- Eclipse and all is good, i can test on the last emulator i created.. except access to AVD Manager...

Thanks,

EDIT : SOLVED
I could launch again my AVD Manager after deleting my AVD settings in %USER%\.android\avd . I think i had something wrong in some AVD...

Comment: Go to `Run > Run Configurations...`. Select your app under `Android Application`, after that the `Target` tab and select `Always prompt to pick device`. Run, select `Launch a new Android Virtual Device` and click `Manager...`, can you see the avd manager now?

Comment: Thanks for answer, the click on "Manager" doesn't do anything, no window or message... I'm trying to download the SDK again. I used the bundle before.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I could launch again my AVD Manager after deleting my AVD settings in `%USER%\.android\avd` .

I think i had something wrong in some AVD...

Comment: I experienced the same issue while upgrading to Android Studio 4.2.0 on MacOS. Additionally I could not select devices Android Studio always was showing "Loading Devices...". I have cleaned up the folder and the issue has been solved.