# AVD Manager won't open, although SDK Manager opens and works

Tags: android, android-virtual-device

I am having a problem similar to this question:

[AVD Manager don't start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13470388/avd-manager-dont-start)

but I do not understand the answer and how it worked.  I cannot find AVD anything, anywhere.

My AVD Manager had been working fine and well and then suddenly it stopped. 
I am not 100% sure  if it was working well before I added on the Kindle Fire emulator because I had already had some AVDs set up and didn't try to create a new one before I added this in.

I updated ADT and I am pretty sure it is an android configuration problem, not Eclipse.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, then I realized I had Java EE running in the top left corner, not just Java. In the write hand corner, exit out of the Java EE and start a just Java one, and it will have the AVD Manager you seek.

Comment: thanks for this - Eclipse was partially corrupt I had to erase and reinstall

Answer (score 0):

Yep, I had this too. It is caused by a corrupted AVD image. I followed the instructions (and added a comment) to the below Google Code issue;

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=41024

Follow the instructions there and enjoy the remaining AVD insufficiencies... :S

Comment: Hi - thank you for your response.  I don't see where the instructions are in the link you posted. Am I not looking in the right spot? Thanks.

Comment: Oh sorry, that was the wrong link- I shall edit...
Correct link now! Apologies again.